# Recovering the different Validation Exception subtypes from a validating XmlReader

Tags: validation, .net-core, locale, xmlreader

I used to use an XmlValidatingReader in my .NET Framework based program.
When Validating an XML file against its XSD, it then gave me an Exception subtype such as "Sch_InvalidElementContentExpecting" within the (non-public) GetRes Property of the validation Exceptions.

This code could then be used to provide the Application User a meaningful (for an accountant) analysis of the problems encountered.

Migrating this to .NET 5.0, I needed to replace this class instantiation by a call to the XmlReader.Create(reader, xmlReaderSettings) method.

Now the GetRes Property contains something like "The element {0} has invalid child element {1}. List of possible elements expected: {2}." instead.

The Content of this GetRes property is probably also language dependent, although https://github.com/microsoft/dotnet/issues/474 indicates that .NET core have no localized messages.

So, in order to get the different validation error subtypes again, I might (at some point in the future) have to check against and know the localized error messages.

Are they to be found somewhere ?
Or can one depend upon or somehow ensure that the content will always be in English ?

Or is there a better way ?